# Unable to upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I just bought a new HP laptop that runs Ubuntu 12.04. The current Ubuntu version is 14.04 and I wanted to upgrade to it. After starting up my laptop for the first time, I headed to the update manager. There were about 470 updates (security ones) and one for ubuntu 12.10. How can the update for 12.10 still be available when support to it has ended?

I started the update , but unfortunately due to a really slow internet connection, I wasn't able to complete it. Meanwhile, I did have a trusty tahr DVD, which I suspect was not fully complete (the size was only 470 MB as compared to 900 MB which I read on a blog). So, I stopped the update and ran the DVD, which again unfortunately did not boot up.

I checked if the DVD was correct and gong by the ubuntu forums, I should have booted up. The DVD was quite proper (the files and folders were as it should be and the ISO image was burned properly (using disk startup)).

So, after all of this, with all options exhausted , I tried to use the update manager. The 470 updates showed, but the system asked for a partial update. I did do that too, but it stopped halfway, asked me to insert the trusty tahr DVD.

Please help. I am pretty new to unpbuntu and don't really understand what to do now.

Comment: why cant you do a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04... http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you have a new laptop the best option here would be to go for a fresh installation Download iso from here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

In case you have problems with DVD setup go for a Bootable USB. A clean installation is always better for a long run and for further updates.

Comment: but I want to keep my documents and all installed programs.